# xsane fails because of a non-existing printer

Tags: scanner, xsane

I try to run xsane and get the following error box:

```
Failed to open device: hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_MFP_.... Error during device I/O
```

This makes sense since I am not connected to that printer now - this printer is at work and I am now at home and connected to another printer (Brother).

However, because of this error, xsane won't start and I cannot scan. How can I tell xsane to ignore this non-existing printer and let me scan with the connected one?

EDIT: additionally, xsane gives a lot of errors of the form:

```
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
...
```

I am not sure how these are related to the problem above.

EDIT 2: when I run

```
scanimage -L
```

I get the same non-existent printer:

```
device `hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M426dw?zc=NPIC01B5E' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_MFP_M426dw all-in-one
```